# Making Wildfly setup-script output more useful information

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

When setting up Wildfly with a .cli script (`jboss-cli.sh/bat --file=something.cli`) there is a lot of output in the form:

```
{
    "outcome" : "success",
    "result" : {}
}
```

or similar for failure.

This is unfortunately not very useful for debugging, and using `IF (output == success)` does not really help as any echo commands in the `IF` block are run regardless of the outcome of the conditional. See: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3662

Furthermore wildfly does not allow for empty `IF` blocks.

Is there any other useful way of filtering out the existing outcome and instead outputting something more useful for tracing and debugging?